# How do I find mysql query respose time and show it on UI while retrieving BLOB objects

Tags: mysql-workbench

I want to show query retrieval time for every query fired on Mysql. And show its details to UI user.

Comment: Somebody Help Me. I want Show Total Retrival Time  on Html page...

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from the action output pane:

[image]

It can be hidden (but shows up on errors automatically). Use the icons in the upper right corner to switch the lower (or right/left) panes on and off.